# Can't call a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have this code:

```js
function myFunction() {

  console.log("Something")

  this.somethingElse = event => console.log("Something else")

}
```

When I evoke the function using `myFunction()` I get ***Something*** printed out in the console. But evoking `myFunction.somethingElse()` throws an error saying `myFunction.somethingElse()` is not a function.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: `this` inside the function refers to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, `this` in a function, is the context in which the function is called. In other words, the object which is invoking the function.

In your case, when you do `myFunction()`, you are essentially calling `window.myFunction()`. So the `this` becomes `window`.

So your function will print the console - `Something`.
It will add `somethingElse` in your `window`.
So if you try to access `myFunction().somethingElse` is wrong, Because `somethingElse` is not part of your function.

But if you try to execute `myFunction()` and then `somethingElse`, it will print in the console - `Something else`.

```js
function myFunction() {

  console.log("Something")

  this.somethingElse = event => console.log("Something else")

}

myFunction();

somethingElse()
```

Comment: *"In your case, when you do `myFunction()`, you are essentially calling `window.myFunction()`. So the `this` becomes `window`."* This is not correct. It may appear so for global functions, but since `this` also points to `window` in functions that are *not* global, thinking about it this way does more harm than good IMO.

Comment: I was talking about the particular question. In this scenario, it is referring to the `window`. Isn't it ?

Comment: Maybe my comment wasn't clear. Yes, `this` refers to `window`, but **not** because the OP is "essentially calling `window.myFunction()`". That's the wrong way to think about it. The fact that `this` points `window` is simply a special case and cannot be explained with the function being invoked as a "method" of the `window` object.

Comment: I was just making a point that in this case, when a function is declared it will get attached to `window`. So if we call without any object reference, `this` inside the function will be pointing to the `window`. If it was called with respect to an object, as in `obj.myFunction`, `this` will be referring to the `obj`. I agree it will not be the case always. But that's why I mentioned `in your case`.

Comment: *"when a function is declared it will get attached to `window`"* That's only the case for global functions. Consider `function foo() { function bar() { console.log(this); }; bar(); }; foo();`. `bar` is not global and still `this` inside of it points to `window`. Hence why I am saying that this explanation is misleading. It doesn't explain what's actually happening.

Comment: In your example also, you can see that first `foo` is called in context of `window`. So `this` is referring to `window` inside `foo`. Now when you call `bar()` inside `foo`, still the context is `window`. Ans hence `this` inside `bar` will be `window`. I am agreeing with you that it will not be the case always. But I have tried to explain it as clearly as possible.

Comment: What `this` refers to in `foo` has no impact on `bar`! Your understanding is not correct. Consider this example then: `var obj = {foo() { function bar() { console.log(this); bar(); }}; obj.foo();`. `this` inside `foo` is `obj`. `this` inside `bar` is `window`.

Comment: @FelixKling There is a missing closing `}` at your last example. Also `bar()` is within `bar` function `var obj = {
  foo() { 
    function bar() { 
      console.log(this); 
    }
    bar()
  }
}; obj.foo()`

Comment: @guest271314: Too late to edit ;) Hope the point is clear though.

Comment: Yup I agree with you. My understanding is that the `this` inside a function is the context in which it is called. When the `context` is not provided it refers to the `global scope`. In case `myFunction()` was called directly there was no scope provided, hence it was referring to `window` as `this` inside it. Now when you have called `foo` with respect to `obj`, `this` inside `foo` is referring to `obj`. Now when `bar` is being called, there is no `context` and it's referring to `global` scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can `return` `this`, then call the function using return value of function call, optionally using `new` keyword to prior to function invocation

```
function myFunction() {

  console.log("Something")

  this.somethingElse = event => console.log("Something else")
  return this
}

var fn = new myFunction();
fn.somethingElse();
```

Comment: Don't return from a constructor.

Comment: @AndrewLi Can you share reasons for not returning a value where `new` is used prior to function invocation?

Comment: JavaScript *already does this for you*, it returns the new instance. It's just redundant and isn't executed IIRC.

Comment: Whenever you are creating an instance of a function using `new`, essentially you are creating a new object, and providing it's reference to the new vairable `fn`. So even if you dont return `this`, the variable `somethingElse` will be available in the `fn`. It would have been other case if you have called the `myFunction` directly without `new`.

Comment: @AndrewLi Will leave code unadjusted for context of relation to helpful comments. Another option would be to just return the function `function myFunction() {
  console.log("Something")
  var somethingElse = event => console.log("Something else")
  return somethingElse
} var fn = myFunction(); fn()`

Comment: @AndrewLi it _is_ redundant, but it _is_ also executed. For instance, you could write a specialized constructor that memoizes instances with equivalent values by alternatively checking a `Map` and returning an instance declared with the same input value, e.g. `var cache = new Map(); function MyClass(input) { if (cache.has(input)) return cache.get(input); this.value = input; cache.set(input, this); }`

Answer (score 0):

I invoked this inner function by returning it as the value of an object's property (i.e. a 'method' in JavaScript) like so:

```
function myFunction() {

  console.log("Something")

  return {
    somethingElse: function() {
      console.log("Something else");
    }
  }
}

myFunction().somethingElse()
```